# Elan touchpad not working correctly after logging into Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, touchpad, xubuntu

I used lubuntu recently but decided to switch to xubuntu to try it out.
On lubuntu, my touchpad worked fine.

But on xubuntu, my touchpad works correctly only when I am on the login screen.
After login, it accepts some inputs and ignores others.
It always accepts clicks (left & right) but isn't sensitive to all my touches.

I've tried changing sensitivity settings in `Mouse and Touchpad Settings`.
Also tried disabling and re-enabling the Trackpad and other commands I've found online like
`sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps`

For reference, my touchpad is called "Elan Touchpad" and I'm a noob.

Here's an output of `xinput list`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Telink Wireless Receiver Consumer Control id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Telink Wireless Receiver Mouse            id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse          id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Elan Touchpad                             id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Telink Wireless Receiver System Control   id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Telink Wireless Receiver                  id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam: HD WebCam                      id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Telink Wireless Receiver Consumer Control id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Send the output of xinput list.

Comment: I added the xinput details @MacHenni